# How can I show sample size in the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code. I have the figure I want. But I would also like to put the sample sizes next to the labels. For example, there maybe 100 points between 90-92, 500 points between 92-94 and I would like to show these numbers next to labels or somewhere in the figure. Could you please help?

```
makeQuantiles <- function(x, probs = seq(0.9, 1, by = 0.02)) {
  cut(x, breaks = qu <- quantile(x, probs = probs),
      labels = names(qu)[-1], include.lowest = TRUE)
}
foo1$quantile<-makeQuantiles(foo1$mnqtp)
ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon( data=usamap, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group),colour="black", fill="white" )+
  geom_point(data=na.omit(foo1),aes(x=lon,y=lat,color=quantile))+
  coord_map(projection = "mercator")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = c(.93,.20),panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "#808080"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic idea is to add the counts to the labels in `cut(...)`.

```
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
N <- 1000
df <- data.frame(lon = sample(-125:-65,N,replace=T), 
                 lat = sample(25:50,N,replace=T),
                 mqntp=sample(1:N,N,replace=T))

# you start here...
makeQuantiles <- function(x, probs = seq(0.9, 1, by = 0.02)) {
  qu <- quantile(x, probs=probs)
  br <- cut(x, breaks = qu, labels = names(qu)[-1], 
            include.lowest = TRUE)
  ct <- table(br)
  cut(x, breaks = qu, labels = paste0(names(qu)[-1]," (",ct,")"), 
      include.lowest = TRUE)
}
df$quantile <- makeQuantiles(df$mqntp)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(na.omit(df), aes(x=lon,y=lat,color=quantile))+geom_point()
```

[image]